# Saved token security risk. Is token/refresh token safe?

Tags: security, oauth, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, facebook-oauth

With OAuth I can get an access token and keep in my DB(or use Refresh token and do the same). But isn't this a security risk? Becuase any internal developer can use this and access the data with out the client knowing about it. Earlier when we had passwords, since the password is hashed a developer could not use it.

eg: O365 mail access given by an app in the company. And developer reads the email of another employee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access tokens are typically not stored in a database in OAuth.

Refresh tokens are, but when a client wants to use a refresh token, it also needs a client id and secret. The client secret is like a password, given to a client when it is registered with the authorization server and should be stored salted and hashed in the database.

So a rogue developer cannot just steal a refresh token from the database and use it to impersonate a client.

Comment: hashing is not reversible so encryption is the solution it seems

Comment: Why does it need to be reversible? I'm talking about the client secret being stored salted and hashed. All the authorization server needs to do when the client uses the refresh token is determine if the client id and secret are correct. No need to know the plain-text password for that.

Comment: to make sure my understanding is correct 1) client secret (hashed) 2)RefreshToken (not hashed) , 3) Client-id(not hashed) 4) Access Token (not hashed) but some access token last for 60 days and in this case we do not need a refresh token, this seems a risk. Now since client secret is hashed, when client need to send this hashed client secret, could the authorization server read it? (if #2 , #3 & #4 items are hashed then the problem is even bigger.

Comment: The client does not send the hashed client secret. It sends the plain text client secret. The authorization server then takes the secret, adds salt, hashes it and compares it with the stored salted hash. Id it matches, a new access token is generated. Access tokens should be short-lived (hours) as you have a refresh token to renew. So yes, the authorization server has access to the plain-text client secret when the refresh flow executes. It does however not store that secret in a reversible way.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an internal security threat like this you can hash or encrypt the tokens before storing them, basically adopting the same approach that you would do for passwords. Of course this makes sense only when the developer has no access to the encryption key or hash key...